# meaning of 1" baseplate fitting to mount to a standard 1" feedthrough port

Tags: machining, threads

I was looking at [this page](https://www.lesker.com/newweb/sample_manipulation/rotarydrives_dynamic_oring.cfm?pgid=0&highlight=FMH-25SS) to figure out how I would install a manipulator onto my chamber.

It says 1" baseplate fitting to mount to a standard 1" feedthrough port"

So, I would have to have a tapped hole of 1 inch in diameter. I am not sure what the thread turn number is going to be.

In solidworks, I see that I have 1-12, 1-14, and 1-8.

Should I be able to assume one of the three just based on what they call "standard?"

Comment: Looking at the drawing of your part, why do you think the 1" hole needs to be tapped? Isn't the part effectively just a 1" nut and bolt, with the rotating seal stuff going down the center of the bolt?

Answer (score 1):

You can call that style of mounting similar to a "bulkhead" fitting, or through-the wall. The hole does not need to be tapped, just a clearance hole for the fitting to pass through, the nut then goes on the other side of the wall, holding the fitting in the wall. Per the drawing, if the wall is thicker than 1.25", then you will have to tap the wall to hold the fitting. If that's the case, you will have to contact the MFG for the thread size as its not annotated on the drawing.

Comment: If the wall thickness exceeds 1.25" another option other than tapping would be a counterbore to accomplish a 1.25" wall thickness at the  location